# store video file on external sdcard in ionic cordova

Tags: android, ios, video, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have done coding for take video using [Media capture plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) and I am also using [File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and [File transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). I have done with taking video and store in internal storage in specific folder.

I am doing this in both  **android** and **IOS**.

Now, what I want, is there any way to check weather device has external sd card inserted or not and then save video on sd card instead of internal storage.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // Check that the SDCard is mounted
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");


        // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

                output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

                Toast.makeText(ActivityContext, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
                return null;
            }
        }


        // Create a media file name

        // For unique file name appending current timeStamp with file name
        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                             .format(date.getTime());

        File mediaFile;

        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

            // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file name
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Follow this link for your reference, this link will help you to store video file on external sdcard in ionic cordova.

http://androidexample.com/Camera_Video_Capture_And_Save_On_SDCard_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=123

I hope you solve your problem very soon.